# Работа со строками FASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Рассматривая  S и T как символьные массивы (строки), решить следующую задачу:
проверить на равенство строки S и T при условии, что пробелы не учитываются, и записать ответ 1 (равны) или 0 в регистр AL.

```
S DB 200 DUP(?)
T DB 200 DUP(?)



use16
org 100h



  cld 
  mov cx,T-S
  mov si,S
  mov di, T
repe cmpsb
   jnz notequal

   equal:
      mov AL,1
      int 21h

   notequal:
      mov AL,0
      int 21h
;----------------
S DB 200 DUP(?)
T DB 200 DUP(?)
```

Я не понимаю почему у меня не работает проверка и как убрать пробелы помогите

Comment: А с чем трудности? Символ 0x20 отследить не получается?

Comment: Самое элементарное решение, ИМХО, пройтись по обоим массивам и убрать пробелы, далее обычный cmp, как вы и делаете.

Comment: Проблема в том если массив одинаковый он всеравно будет выполнять строчку jnz notequal и переходить к notequal: а мне надо что бы когда строки были одинаковы он переходил в  equal:

Comment: или я не так делаю...я просто не понимаю почему он постоянно выполняет jnz notequal даже если массивы одинаковы

Comment: Забудьте про цепочечные команды вроде `repe cmpsb`. Сверяйте сами побайтно строки в цикле, при этом, заодно предварительно проверяйте не является ли очередной символ пробелом и если является то просто пропускаете его (сдвигая указатель) и возвращаясь к началу цикла

Comment: Интересно просто, какую именно функцию `int 21h` вы хотите вызвать? Если надеетесь на `0`, то код возврата в `al` в неё не передаётся... Если `4Ch`, то где инициализация `ah`?